# NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler Hijacked by Third Party SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Edit: for those who're wondering what that SDK is, it's a Chinese clone of Flurry, ==>> Umeng.

Edit 2: there's actually a **disable crash log handling** option in that weird SDK, which will make my **uncaughtExceptionHandler** get called again. But still I am very much interested in how that SDK did the trick in the first place.

I'm playing with some third party iOS analytics SDK. Weird discovery:

Originally (before I added the SDK), I had a **UncaughtExceptionHandler** in my appDelegate.m. It worked fine. Whenever an exception occurred when testing on a real iDevice, it printed some log to the console.

```
//Worked like charm before I added that weird analytics SDK
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

Then I added that weird analytics SDK (all I did was drop the .a lib into my project and add one line to my appDelegate.m, as mentioned below), then all of a sudden, my **uncaughtExceptionHandler** never gets called.

```
//To make sure my uncaughtExceptionHandler was not set a second time by that SDK,
//I set and reset again, before and after I initialized that weird SDK
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
[WeirdAnalyticsSDK startWithAppkey:@"XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX"];
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

As it turns out, no matter what I do, as long as I initialized that SDK in my appDelegate, my **uncaughtExceptionHandler** just won't get called when an exception occurs.

Can someone help me please? What on earth that weird SDK did to my **uncaughtExceptionHandler**?

Comment: What is the this third party SDK?  It's implementation details are probably important to answer this question, so we'll need the name of it...

Comment: Perhaps the SDK is calling NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler() later than you think. Try setting a breakpoint on `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`, run your app, and see if you can find a place where the SDK resets it again. (In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint Navigator, click the + at the bottom, Add Symbolic Breakpoint.)

Comment: You use the word 'weird' a lot in your post: thinking in this way can harm your ability to meet problems objectively.  There is nothing 'weird' about an SDK registering it's own UncaughtExceptionHandler. In fact, it makes complete sense that an Analytics SDK would aggressively register for this handler; if it is to provide crash-logging as part of its reports. Perhaps the authors could improve this functionality by having their handler pass-through calls to any existing handler (thereby acting as a proxy). Why not get in touch with the authors and let them know this is a problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your `WeirdAnalyticsSDK` sends crash reports to the server and `overridse` the `uncaughtExceptionHandler`.

It happend to me while using the `hockeyapp SDK`. I ignored the init lines for the sdk in debug mode and everything worked fine.

You should also check if your `WeirdAnalyticsSDK` has some `enable debug mode` flags.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the OP's exception handler still isn't used when he reset it, which was **after** the sdk was initialised.

Comment: Yes, you are right it should work, but it's possible that the SDK reset the handler when he sends tracking data to the server. Anyway it's hard to find the problem here without the sdk implementation or sdk real name :D

Comment: @danypata See my edited answer. I added the real name at the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, We should hook the handler which the third SDK used.

- We should register the third sdk's ExceptionHandler by send msg to the third sdk.
- We save the handler that that the third sdk used. Using the "NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler" get the handler.
- We handle the exception by "NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler". Fourth, we handle the excetion by ourselves using the foucntion "UncaughtExceptionHandlerMaple"
- In the UncaughtExceptionHandlerMaple fouction, we should execute the third sdk handler by --- "_previousHandler(exception)"

```

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //register the third sdk
    // save the handler by the third SDK
    _previousHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    // setting the handler for yourself
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler (&UncaughtExceptionHandlerMaple);
}

void UncaughtExceptionHandlerMaple(NSException *exception) {
    //handle yourself logic for the exception
    //code ...
    //recover the third sdk's exception handle
    _previousHandler(exception);
}
```

```

Comment: You need to be more specific about your answer - add some comment.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem.

You just need to invoke `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` after any possible one call `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` . Here is the sample code.

```
static void myExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {

    /* do your logic of exception handler */

    // invoke WeirdAnalyticsSDK's exception handler if needed
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.hijackedHandler(exception);
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    /* configure WeirdAnalyticsSDK which maybe call `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` */

    // remember to claim property hijackedHandler in header file
    self.hijackedHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    // make sure you call `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` after any possible one call NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);
    return YES;
}
```